# How to unescape a query string

Tags: python

I have a query string as follows:

```
cmd%5Blogin_user%5D%5Busername%5D=dfdsfdsf&cmd%5Blogin_user%5D%5Bpassword%5D=dsfsdf
```

How do I unescape it in python?

Comment: That's a query string, not JSON.

Comment: What are you wanting to escape?

Comment: transform all the % leading escaped string to normal string. and change + to space etc.

Comment: Python has a standard module for this. What have you tried?

Comment: btw....if this really is a query string... please tell me you're not passing passwords around in the address bar?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import urllib

print urllib.unquote("cmd%5Blogin_user%5D%5Busername%5D=dfdsfdsf&cmd%5Blogin_user%5D%5Bpassword%5D=dsfsdf")
```

Comment: outputs `cmd[login_user][username]=dfdsfdsf&cmd[login_user][password]=dsfsdf`

Comment: there are no `+`s that i can see

Comment: use `urllib.unquote_plus` to convert back '+' to spaces

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the following function:
xml.sax.saxutils.unescape()